# Is there a way to align multiple lists that has the same index position?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
[
    ['104314', '104319'],
    ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)40-5'],
    ['N(1)F-T15', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']
]
```

What I need to do is to get the first item and make it as a key to a dictionary. Beyond the first item I need to align them with the position of the first items to make a list of dictionaries something like this, I really don't know how to do this in a Pythonic way:

```
[
    {'104314': ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)F-T15']},
    {'104319': ['N(1)40-5', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = [
...     ['104314', '104319'],
...     ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)40-5'],
...     ['N(1)F-T15', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']
... ]
>>> [{k: v} for k, *v in zip(*mylist)]
[{'104314': ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)F-T15']}, {'104319': ['N(1)40-5', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']}]
```

However, it's kind of pointless to have single key dicts, so you can try this dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, *v in zip(*mylist)}
{'104314': ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)F-T15'], '104319': ['N(1)40-5', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']}
```

Comment: Compare your output with the output in the question. They DON'T Match. The OP wants list of dictionaries. What you get is just a single dictionary

Comment: @Bazingaa Edited to include a list comprehension version.

Comment: @PyHunterMan If this solved your question, be sure to mark it as accepted for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2, you can do:

```
ml=[
   ['104314', '104319'],
   ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)40-5'],
   ['N(1)F-T15', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']
]
```

For a list of dicts:

```
>>> [{t[0]:list(t[1:])} for t in zip(*ml)]
[{'104314': ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)F-T15']}, {'104319': ['N(1)40-5', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0']}]
```

For a single dict (if all keys are unique):

```
>>> {t[0]:list(t[1:]) for t in zip(*ml)}
{'104319': ['N(1)40-5', 'N(1)I-TJS1/0'], '104314': ['N(1)40-35', 'N(1)F-T15']}
```